# Magento connect not showing available update

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, upgrade

We have a client with an old Magento version 1.7.0.0 we wanted to upgrade this version to the latest version.

So what we did is made a copy to a our test environment, used Magento connect manager and updated it to the latest version 1.9.2.4. worked liked a charm.

The client tested this environment and everything was correct.

Now we wanted to update the original site to this version. But when we logged in we saw that the version in Magento connect manager showt that this was version 1.9.2.4.

How is this possible? Can it be that with the use of Magento Connect Manager that our test server somehow stored at magento our latest installed version with the secret key?

After this I tried using the following solution:

```
chmod 550 mage ./mage mage-setup . ./mage config-set preferred_state stable ./mage sync ./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force php shell/indexer.php reindexall rm -rf downloader/.cache/ var/cache/
```

But this didn't work at all and gave me tons of errors so we placed back a backup.

Answer (score 0):

The easier solution I think is to recopy your test server magento 1.9 to your online server. Just do a backup of the old server before doing this. It can be done in fews minutes if you have already all file and DB ready.

Comment: This isn't a sollution, since it has to be done with the live situation, db and server.

Comment: I tested this way of updating and the result is that we can't login anymore to the admin page.

Comment: Sometime it happen when you using same example.com and test.example.com. Use different browser thant the original you use. It is a mistaken from your computer. We have the same issue when doing that. We always use explorer for our site and when we are not able to connect, we use edge or chrome and it's work fine.